# Using Win7 key to activate Win10 is valid for clean instalations?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-activation, license-key

I installed Win10 Pro using my Win7 Pro license key in my laptop with Win10 Home Basic when it was free to do it, making a new clean installation, and now I have Win10 Pro activated with that key. Microsoft announced that this method would be no longer avaliable.

If Microsoft look up for the hardware on their activation servers will put me the Win10 Home Basic license key?

Microsoft associate this key to an upgraded Win7 or is no longer valid to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean install Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1004961/clean-install-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks @Run5k for the reference, I think it's a bit distinct. I updated the question.

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández If my answer was useful/helpful to you please accept it if you feel appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1004961/clean-install-windows-10/1004964#1004964) that I'll quote as well:

> If you have taken the free update for Windows 10, then Microsoft
>   recorded the activation for your hardware on their activation servers.
>   You can wipe the computer and proceed with a clean install.
>
> During the install, Windows 10 will ask for a key, but you can skip
>   this step. Once you have network drivers installed it will go out to
>   the internet and activate automatically.

**You can wipe your system just fine and it will be activated automatically.**

As @[Joy](https://superuser.com/users/722171/joy) said, once you activate your product key for Pro version (and it works) it will reserve your Windows 10 Pro activation for your system (*ignoring *whatever the version you had* product key*). Otherwise, it will show invalid product key and reject to activate it.

If it shows as activated with Windows 10 Pro, there is **no need** to afraid of invalid product key.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members. However, you should **not** post another person's answer as a "new" answer. We should either post that as a *comment,* or mark the OP's question as a duplicate of the one that you referenced.

Comment: @Run5k alright, because I think the question I mentioned is very similar I'll mark this as duplicate. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What if the original laptop did not come with windows 7? I have a Win7 Pro license key and made a clean install of Win10 Pro under a laptop with Win10 Home Basic. If Microsoft look up for the hardware on their activation servers will put me the Win10 Home Basic license key?

Updated question.

Comment: We could use command line "slmgr /dlv" to display license information and check the existing activation status. If it shows as activated with Windows 10 Pro, there is no need to afraid of invalid product key. Once you activate with Windows 10 Pro, it will reserve your Windows 10 Pro activation,  otherwise, it will show invalid product key and reject to activate it.

Comment: @Joy that's right! Can I add that to my answer? Thanks

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira no problem, you could do it just as you like. ^ ^